# Setting input type text values for ngdialog

Tags: angularjs, controller, loading

I am trying to set values for input type="text" in ngDialog from server, but I find that populating even with dummy values does not make the values show up "in the dialog" - as in if I were to set values in form using javascript I get to see them on the textbox in the view. However, that does not seem to work with ngDialog, - inspite of binding the textbox with ng-model and name attributes. So my question is, for ngDialog setting the text using $modelValue will not show the values in the text box?

```
For e.g -

$scope.myForm.myTextBox.$modelValue = "xyz" does not show up

The form in html will be similar to what is shown below -

<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="AddUserController">

    <div class="text-center">
        <label class="sub-header">Add User</label>
    </div>

    <form action="...r" method="POST" name="myForm">
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="myTextBox"
                    name="myTextBox" required 
                    ng-minlength = "1" ng-maxlength="50"
                    placeholder="Enter First Name" bs-typeahead>                    
            </div>
         </div>
       </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/9vbowtfqNCS3aSKzNUUA?p=preview

```
app.controller('AddUserController', function($scope){

  $scope.myTextBox ="Some name"

});
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, this is not on an ngDialog, I was asking about ngDialog.

Comment: @user4002112 still this same rules http://plnkr.co/edit/9vbowtfqNCS3aSKzNUUA?p=preview

Comment: This is what happens when things are done without reading the documentation and trying some basic examples :) sorry, I was setting $scope.myForm.myTextBox.$modelValue because it seemed to work in another instance. Did not even strike me that the association was wrong. Thanks so much, you saved me from frustration.